# What is the parameter values for the function to satisfy the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have been trying to solve the following problem below using Mathematica to no avail. I need some help on this.

If  have the following function

$$F=bx\left(1-d(1+{x}^{a})^{-c}\exp(-b{x}^{a})\right)+(a-1)(b+c+bx)\left(1-d(1+x^a)^{-c}\exp(-bx^a)\right)-ac(b+c+bx)d(1+x^a)^{-1-c}\exp(-bx^a)$$.

For what values of $a$,$b$,$c$ and $d$ would the following occurs

1. $F=0$
2. $F>0$
3. $F<0$

If $b>0$, $a>0$, $c>0$, $d>0$ and $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you

Comment: Go to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to properly format functions.

Comment: Thanks Arbuja for the edit. I should have used the right format but it is worth noting that it is a learning process for me.